# Cross-Site AJAX using CORS on IIS (ASP.net) fails when setRequestHeader is used

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, cors

OK, so I am trying to enable CORS on my ASP.net server so that I can test some javascript against my Web API using jsFiddle.  My web forms page calls the EnableCors function (below) on the pageInit event.

```
Public Sub EnableCors(Optional Origin As String = "", Optional Methods As String = "", Optional Headers As String = "")
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", vbNVL(Origin, "*"))
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", vbNVL(Methods, "*"))
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", vbNVL(Headers, "*"))
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
End Sub
```

The vbNVL function simply replaces any empty string with the second parameter value.  So, the values for the first 3 headers just end up being "*" if no parameters were passed to the Sub.

[Using my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkappel/jhd9xfys/), everything works great until I append header values to the request object, then it fails saying "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing".  Please take a look at the fiddle, and toggle setHeaders variable to false on line one to see it succeed.  Line 31 is where the variable is being used.  This is a super simple example.

Can someone please help me figure out why this fails when I use the setRequestHeader method on the XMLHttpRequest object?  Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention, for testing purposes I am calling the EnableCors procedure with no parameters.  So Origin, Methods, and Headers are all set to *.

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE:** It doesn't seem that CORS is the issue, it seems as if there may be a bug in the XMLHttpRequest object, though I can't be certain.  However, since the cross site request does succeed if I don't add any custom headers, it seems CORS isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the enableCors attribute to the top of your WebAPI contronller, I.e.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://youroriginaddress.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

The following tutorial should be of help to you also:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Let me know how it goes. ;)

Comment: I'm not using WebAPI, I'm using Web Forms.  Is there some way to do the same thing using Web Forms?  I think that's what I'm doing with my procedure I posted above, but maybe not?